# python-kafka producer timeout in uwsgi python app

Tags: apache-kafka, uwsgi, kafka-python

I'm having a problem communicating with my kafka server when my flask application is running with uwsgi/nginx. When I start the application with python on the command line, everything goes through just fine. But when I run it with the uwsgi emperor, my producer is timing out waiting for a response. Creating the producer works as expected; I only have a problem trying to send a new message. I've verified the message never reaches the server, but the exception thrown waiting for a response is simply "Timeout after waiting for 5 seconds".

How do I troubleshoot this issue? Everything in the application works fine, I just can't send any kafka messages. Do I need any special configurations to allow the application to communicate over other sockets?

Things I've tried:

- Setting close-on-exec in my ini config
- disabling threading
- limiting to a single process